# Python- How to count the number of occurrences of a partial string in a list of strings

Tags: python

If I have a list, say list = [abc are all letters, elephants, bananas are yellow, apples are fruits] or something of that sort, how would I count the number of times the word 'are' shows up in this list?

Comment: Please post real Python data and show what you have tried yourself.

Comment: Using a loop. What did you try?

Answer (score 4):

```
los =  ["abc are all letters, elephants", "bananas are yellow, apples are fruits"]

sum((itm.count("are") for itm in los))
```

Comment: please look at [answer]

Comment: Can you please clarify which part of the [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guideline am I violating.

Comment: code-only answers aren't useful for the community

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name, but here is something that would work:

```
my_list = ["abc are all letters", "elephants", "bananas are yellow", "apples are fruits"]
count = 0
for string in my_list:
    if "are" in string:
       count += 1
```